# Elixir: use vs import

Tags: elixir

What's the difference between `use` and `import`?

> use is a simple mechanism for using a given module into the current context

https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#import/2

> Imports function and macros from other modules

Looks like one difference is `import` let's you pick out the specific functions/macros whereas `use` brings everything in.

Are there other differences? When would you use one over the other?

Comment: Quick summary:   
`import Module` brings in functions to be used inside your module.  
  
   
`use Module` brings in functions to be used AND exposes them publicly on your module

Answer (score 256, accepted):

**`import Module`** brings all the Functions and Macros of `Module` un-namespaced into your module.

**`require Module`** allows you to use macros of `Module` but does not import them. (Functions of `Module` are always available namespaced.)

**`use Module`** first `requires` module and then calls the `__using__` macro on `Module`.

Consider the following:

```rb
defmodule ModA do
  defmacro __using__(_opts) do
    IO.puts "You are USING ModA"
  end

  def moda() do
    IO.puts "Inside ModA"
  end
end

defmodule ModB do
  use ModA

  def modb() do
    IO.puts "Inside ModB"
    moda()     # <- ModA was not imported, this function doesn't exist
  end
end
```

This will not compile as `ModA.moda()` has not been imported into `ModB`.

The following will compile though:

```rb
defmodule ModA do
  defmacro __using__(_opts) do
    IO.puts "You are USING ModA"
    quote do          # <--
      import ModA     # <--
    end               # <--
  end

  def moda() do
    IO.puts "Inside ModA"
  end
end

defmodule ModB do
  use ModA

  def modb() do
    IO.puts "Inside ModB"
    moda()            # <-- all good now
  end
end
```

As when you `use`d `ModA` it generated an `import` statement that was inserted into `ModB`.

Comment: Great answer! For more info: http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html

Comment: Getting in to Elixir, and being from the Python world I'm kinda confused about the modules being `*.ex` files and the `defmodule` blocks, and how you'd pull a module from a file into an iex REPL

Comment: Trying to understand the example/concept. In this particular case you are just demonstrating that the `__using__` method is executed on `use ModA`? It would probably make sense to just use import in `ModB` in the example you have presented correct?

Answer (score 38):

`use` is intended for injecting code into the current module, while `import` is used to, well, import functions for use. You can build a `use` implementation which automatically imports functions for example, as I do with Timex when you add `use Timex` to a module, [take a look at timex.ex if you want to know what I mean](https://github.com/bitwalker/timex/blob/master/lib/timex.ex), it's a very simple example of how to build a module which can be `use`'d

Comment: So is it accurate to say `use` is more general than `import`? That is, the functionality of `import` is a subset of `use`

Comment: `import` is still necessary, as I don't know if it's accurate to say you can reimplement `import` with `use` alone, but I wouldn't be surprised if it's possible. `use` is absolutely more powerful though. You can do very complex things with it, for instance, I make heavy use of `use` in my `exprotobuf` project which you could check out if you want to see it pushed to it's limits. You can extend modules with code, execute code at compile-time, add functions to a module, etc. Basically it combines `import` and the power of macros.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation and references to code.  I think I get it now.  I'm still new to Elixir but I think once I look at more use-cases the differences will be obvious.

Comment: Hey no problem, another great place to look would be the Phoenix web framework. Chris McCord has written a book on Elixir macros, and he uses them heavily in Phoenix (including `use`). It almost definitely be easier to read through for a beginner than `exprotobuf`, but I think I probably push `use` to it's limit in `exprotobuf` so it might be useful just to see how far you can take it.

Comment: `use` actually doesnt do much, it just calls `__using__` on the specified module.

Comment: @bitwalker Why are you using `import` and not `require` in [import Timex.Macros](https://github.com/bitwalker/timex/blob/916673de69ca24dc2359b3df0807a28c2f52cf3f/lib/timex.ex#L45)?

Answer (score 29):

See [«alias, require, and import»](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html) page from the elixir official getting started guide:

```ruby
# Ensure the module is compiled and available (usually for macros)
require Foo

# Import functions from Foo so they can be called without the `Foo.` prefix
import Foo

# Invokes the custom code defined in Foo as an extension point
use Foo
```

### Require

Elixir provides macros as a mechanism for meta-programming (writing code that generates code).

Macros are chunks of code that are executed and expanded at compilation time. This means, in order to use a macro, we need to guarantee its module and implementation are available during compilation. This is done with the `require` directive.

In general a module does not need to be required before usage, except if we want to use the macros available in that module.

### Import

We use `import` whenever we want to easily access functions or macros from other modules without using the fully-qualified name. For instance, if we want to use the `duplicate/2` function from the `List` module several times, we can import it:

```ruby
iex> import List, only: [duplicate: 2]
List
iex> duplicate :ok, 3
[:ok, :ok, :ok]
```

In this case, we are importing only the function `duplicate` (with arity 2) from `List`.

Note that `import`ing a module automatically `require`s it.

### Use

Although not a directive, `use` is a macro tightly related to `require` that allows you to use a module in the current context. The `use` macro is frequently used by developers to bring external functionality into the current lexical scope, often modules.

Behind the scenes, `use` requires the given module and then calls the `__using__/1` callback on it allowing the module to inject some code into the current context. Generally speaking, the following module:

```ruby
defmodule Example do
  use Feature, option: :value
end
```

is compiled into

```ruby
defmodule Example do
  require Feature
  Feature.__using__(option: :value)
end
```

Answer (score 19):

With background from Python/Java/Golang languages, the `import` vs `use` was also confused for me. This will explain code reuse mechanism with some declarative languages examples.

## import

In short, in Elixir, you don't need to import modules. All public functions can be accessed by full-qualified MODULE.FUNCTION syntax:

```
iex()> Integer.mod(5, 2)
1

iex()> String.trim(" Hello Elixir  ")
"Hello Elixir"
```

In Python/Java/Golang, you need to `import MODULE` before you can use functions in that MODULE, e.g Python

```
In []: import math

In []: math.sqrt(100)
Out[]: 10.0
```

Then what `import` in Elixir does might surprise you:

> We use import whenever we want to easily access functions or macros from other modules without using the fully-qualified name

https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html#import

So if you want to type `sqrt` instead of `Integer.sqrt`, `trim` instead of `String.trim`, `import` will help

```
iex()> import Integer
Integer
iex()> sqrt(100)
10.0

iex()> import String
String
iex()> trim(" Hello Elixir    ")
"Hello Elixir"
```

This might cause problems for reading code and when there is name-conflicting so it is [not recommended](http://www.erlang.se/doc/programming_rules.shtml#HDR26) in Erlang (the language that influences Elixir). But there is no such convention in Elixir, you can use it at own-risk.

In Python, the same effect can be done by:

```
from math import *
```

and it only recommended to use [in some special scenarios](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) / interactive mode - for shorter/faster typing.

### use & require

What makes `use`/`require` different is that they relate to "macro" - the concept that does not exist in Python/Java/Golang... family.

**You don't need to `import` a module to use its functions, but you need to `require` a module to use its macros**:

```
iex()> Integer.mod(5, 3) # mod is a function
2

iex()> Integer.is_even(42)
** (CompileError) iex:3: you must require Integer before invoking the macro Integer.is_even/1
    (elixir) src/elixir_dispatch.erl:97: :elixir_dispatch.dispatch_require/6
iex()> require Integer
Integer
iex()> Integer.is_even(42) # is_even is a macro
true
```

Though `is_even` can be written as a normal function, it is a macro because:

> In Elixir, Integer.is_odd/1 is defined as a macro so that it can be used as a guard.

https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html#require

`use`, to excerpt from Elixir doc:

> use requires the given module and then calls the `__using__/1` callback on it allowing the module to inject some code into the current context.

```
defmodule Example do
  use Feature, option: :value
end
```

is compiled into

```
defmodule Example do
  require Feature
  Feature.__using__(option: :value)
end
```

https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html#use

So writing `use X` is same as writing

```
require X
X.__using__()
```

`use/2` [is a macro](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.4.5/Kernel.html#use/2), macro will transform code into other code for you.

You will want to `use MODULE` when you:

- want to access its macros (`require`)
- AND execute `MODULE.__using__()`

Tested on Elixir 1.5

Answer (score 3):

**`use Module`** *requires* `Module` and also calls `__using__` on it.

**`import Module`** brings `Module` functionality into *current context*, not just requires it.

Answer (score 3):

## Import

Makes all functions and macros from a given module accessible inside of the lexical scope where it's called. Keep in mind that in most cases you need only one or more functions/macros to be imported.

Example:

```
defmodule TextPrinter do
  import IO, only: [puts: 1]

  def execute(text) do
    puts(text)
  end
end

iex> TextPrinter.execute("Hello")
Hello
:ok
```

## Use

This macro allows you to inject **any** code in the current module. You should be careful when using external libraries with **`use`**, since you might not be sure what exactly happens behind the scenes.

Example:

```
defmodule Printer do
  defmacro __using__(_opts) do
    quote do
      def execute(text) do
        IO.puts(text)
      end
    end
  end
end

defmodule TextPrinter do
  use Printer
end

iex> TextPrinter.execute("Hello")
Hello
:ok
```

Behind the scene code inside of `__using__` has been injected into `TextPrinter` module.

[By the way, there is more dependency handling instructions in Elixir](https://curiosum.dev/blog/alias-import-require-use-in-elixir).